# How do you change TemplateBindings to Bindings in a button's control template, without repeating the whole control template

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I want to change the background color of a button in its normal, moused-over and pressed states to various shades of green. I am forced to add the following grotesquely verbose `Button.Template` to my button so that I can modify the `RenderMouseOver` and `RenderPressed` attributes to use `Binding` instead of `TemplateBinding`, so that my triggers (in the `Button.Style`) actually take effect instead of being ignored due to the compile time nature of `TemplateBinding`. Is there anyway to override these two attributes more cleanly for an Aero theme than to repeat the entire template binding in its entirety? XAML follows:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonMouseOver.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Button>
      Hello
      <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
            x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" 
            RenderMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{Binding IsPressed}"
            >
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
          </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Button.Template>
      <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
              <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
              <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Button.Style>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Important note**: The control template is necessary only for the Aero theme. For other themes, just having the Button.Style alone will do the job.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you don't create a style to deal with this and just apply it to each button as you see fit? I'm missing the piece that is resisting this behavior...? Seems like a standard button style to me...

Comment: The part that is resisting this behavior is the Aero chrome. I have added a note to highlight this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is to add an attached behavior which disables this with reflection once the Button has Loaded. I don't know if you like this better than to re-template it, but you won't have to include PresentationFramework.Aero and its re-usable

```
<Button behaviors:DisableButtonChromeBehavior.DisableButtonChrome="True"
        ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

The DisableButtonChromeBehavior

```
public static class DisableButtonChromeBehavior 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisableButtonChromeProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached 
        (
            "DisableButtonChrome", 
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(DisableButtonChromeBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnDisableButtonChromePropertyChanged) 
        );
    public static bool GetDisableButtonChrome(DependencyObject obj) 
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(DisableButtonChromeProperty); 
    }
    public static void SetDisableButtonChrome(DependencyObject obj, bool value) 
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisableButtonChromeProperty, value); 
    }
    private static void OnDisableButtonChromePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo, 
                                                             DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        Button button = dpo as Button;
        if (button != null) 
        { 
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true) 
            {
                button.Loaded += OnButtonLoaded; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                button.Loaded -= OnButtonLoaded; 
            } 
        } 
    }
    private static void OnButtonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        Button button = sender as Button; 
        Action action = () =>
            {
                object buttonChrome = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(button, 0);
                Type type = buttonChrome.GetType();
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("RenderMouseOver");
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                {
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(buttonChrome, false, null);
                    propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("RenderPressed");
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(buttonChrome, false, null);
                    propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("RenderDefaulted");
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(buttonChrome, false, null);
                }
            };
        button.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle); 
    } 
}
```

**Update**
There's also the shorter non re-usable way, just doing this in code behind.

```
private void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    object buttonChrome = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(button, 0);
    PropertyInfo renderMouseOverInfo = buttonChrome.GetType().GetProperty("RenderMouseOver");
    if (renderMouseOverInfo != null)
    {
        renderMouseOverInfo.SetValue(buttonChrome, false, null);
    }
}
```

Or (if you don't mind including Aero)

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ButtonChrome_Loaded"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>

void ButtonChrome_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonChrome buttonChrome = sender as ButtonChrome;
    if (buttonChrome != null)
    {
        buttonChrome.RenderMouseOver = false;
        buttonChrome.RenderPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Other than that, I think you don't have any other outs than the solution you pointed yourself (re-templating).

Comment: Whoa, although I am sure this would work, it's even more "verbose" than the XAML inclusion of all of the chrome...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the style to toggle the Background, you can't explicitly set the Background property as you have done here:

```
<Button Background="LightGreen">
```

This will override any style you set. Try this instead:

```
   <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property = "Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
          <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
          <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
```

This should make it so you can get rid of the button template, unless you want to do more in it.

If you would like to get rid of the Aero nonsense, replace the template like so:

```
   <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
```

The drawback here is if you don't want Aero, you don't get any of it and you have to start from scratch with your template.

Comment: My appologies, I have corrected that oversight. However, your solution does not work for the Aero theme and the control template is still necessary.

Comment: @Michael:  Are you looking to use the Aero theme across all operating systems?  If so, because WPF is designed to use the feel of the current Windows OS, there is no other way to force Aero than to override the template and specfically use the Aero resources.

Comment: No, I am looking at figuring out how, when Aero is being used, to change a button's background color in an effective way. Simply setting the Button Style (for Aero) does not work.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are trying to accomplish. The style above should change the background of the button for the given scenarios specified in the trigger. Are you saying that you want to change the background color ONLY when the user is in Aero?

Comment: I'll phrase it as plainly as I can: Even though the background setter works, the Triggers in your Button.Style above DO NOT change the background of a button for their respective button states, when the Aero theme is in effect. Give it a try under Vista or Windows 7. The reason for this is that the Control Template chrome for the Aero theme uses its own triggers for these events, which are specified as TemplatBindings. Thus they cannot be overriden by the specified Button.Style triggers for IsMouseOver and IsPressed.

Comment: My fault, I forgot the button chrome has that stuff built into it. Is that update what you were looking for?

Comment: What I am looking for is how to selectively change (i.e., overide) just the static compile time chrome TemplateBindings to dynamic runtime Bindings without having to copy the entire Control Template from Microsoft's definition for Aero.