# How to disable IsMouseOver trigger from WPF GridViewColumnHeader but have e.g. resize?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can do this with ControlTemplate that does not have trigger for IsMouseOver. However ability to resize columns and the actual space between the columns disappears with the definition below. So how to disable IsMouseOver trigger but keep all other functionality?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" >
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.FontWeight}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Background}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Foreground}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Border  x:Name="Border" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

EDIT: In [Suppress mouse hover effect on GridViewColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148115/suppress-mouse-hover-effect-on-gridviewcolumn) the accepted answer seems to address this problem.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, what behavior are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i want to get rid of the default functionality that changes column header background color when  mouse is over a column header. i want to achieve this with keeping evertything else like ability to ressize columns.

Comment: Here's one way to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432671/how-do-you-change-templatebindings-to-bindings-in-a-buttons-control-template-w (why it is complex ? because that's the parent of the header that is assigning this property)

Comment: thanks, but i don't know which answer you refer and how it should be applied in my case

Comment: ok, i didn't get it. i chose to  add PART_HeaderGripper Thumb in ControlTemplate. that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there was similar questions with answers, i post a version that solves my problem. It probably has some issues but it might give somebody an idea how to solve their problems.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" >
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.FontWeight}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Background}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Foreground}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource  Theme.DataGrid.Cell.Padding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Thumb Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-8,0,0,0"
                               Style="{DynamicResource GridView.ColumnHeader.Gripper.Style}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```